# Python src block sets tabs

Tags: org-babel

Emacs 26.3, Org 9.3

When using python src block, it changes 8 spaces to tab.  When tangling this, python errors with "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation".  How fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> ‘org-src-preserve-indentation’
>
> Default is ‘nil’.  Source code is indented.  This indentation
>      applies during export or tangling, and depending on the context,
>      may alter leading spaces and tabs.  When non-‘nil’, source code is
>      aligned with the leftmost column.  No lines are modified during
>      export or tangling, which is very useful for white-space sensitive
>        languages, such as Python.

So, I've set this variable as local for buffer in the end of the file

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; org-src-preserve-indentation: t
;;; End:
```

Comment: Assume there is a more fundamental solution.